# React-app not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, material-ui, internet-explorer-11

I have a react app and I need it to work in Internet Explorer 11. I use Material-UI and some others tiny libraries. Right now, I just can see a blank page. I tried the next solutions (without success):

1. I added react-app-polyfill for ie11 as my first lines in index.js:

   `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';`
   `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';`
2. In my package.json I added Internet Explorer 11:

   ````
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ],
       "development": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ]
     }```
   ````

And I have the next errors (Translated from spanish):

> Access to property "caller" from a function or object is not allowed in strict mode.
>
> The object doesn't accept the property or function "repeat"

Could somebody more experiencied with this topic help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use react-easy-state to manage the global state of the application. As the documentation says, it is not compatible with Internet Explorer. I removed the library and it worked.